# TimeSpan.Parse Parsing Issue

Tags: c#, timespan

I am trying to parse time using TimeSpan.Parse method; However i get an unexpected result as i am trying to parse this `00:00:45.748` which supposed to be

0 Hours
0 Minutes
45 Seconds
748 Milliseconds

```
TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:45.748")
```

Result :

`00:00:45.7480000`

I want to know why it reads the milliseconds as `7480000` instead of `748` ?

Comment: Looks successful to me.

Comment: it doesn't read .7480000 instead of .748, it prints .7480000 instead of .748. it reads .748

Comment: @MarvinSmit, so how could i print 748 instead of 7480000 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you are showing is that of **displaying** a `TimeSpan` in a textual format.

By default it will show the full range.

The string you have shown actually shows that the parse was successful and you got the right result.

If you want to **format** the `TimeSpan`, use `ToString` with an appropriate `TimeSpan` format string (.NET 4.0 and above).

There are [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) and [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) format strings for `TimeSpan`.

In your case, it looks like you are looking for:

```
myTimeSpan.ToString("hh:mm:ss.FFF")
```

Comment: When i try to use `.ToString("g");`, i get compiler error `Method .ToString() has 0 parameters but is invoked with 1 args`

Comment: @RuneS - What are you calling it on? It should be on a `TimeSpan` instance.

Comment: it is a TimeSpan instance

Comment: @RuneS - I don't think so. Works for me.

Comment: string x = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:45.748").ToString("g");

Comment: I am getting "0:00:45.748" for that, @RuneS

Comment: @RuneS - No idea. Do you have a custom `TimeSpan` class?

Comment: ok it turns out that .Net 3.5 does not support it, fixed when changed to .Net 4

Comment: @RuneS - Oh, yeah... it was added at 4.0 - didn't think about that.

Comment: sorry but when trying to parse `00:00:45.700`, it parses it as `00:00:45.7` .......

Comment: @RuneS - I honestly don't understand why that is an issue. It is correct. Those two `00`s at the end can be discarded and the value is the same.

Comment: for a SRT file, could it be an issue ?

Comment: @RuneS - what is an SRT file?

Comment: @RuneS - frankly, I don't have any idea what effect that would have. You would need to check what the format specification says about this.

Comment: ok thank you very much you really have helped me alooot, and i really appreciate your valuable time!

Answer (score 1):

00:00:45.7480000 == 00:00:45.748

The difference is simply the number of decimal places on the milliseconds

This will format your output as desired:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:45.748");
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff}", ts));
```

The fff is the number of decimal places you want to display (this can be from 1 to 7). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

Note that this will require .NET 4.0 or above

Answer (score 1):

As additional to *[Oded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20024100/447156)*;

From [`TimeSpan.Parse Method (String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> ff - Optional fractional seconds, **consisting of one to seven decimal
>   digits.**

You can use [`The "FFF" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#f3Specifier)

Like;

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:45.748");
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.FFF"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Output will be;

```
00:00:45.748
```

For more informations, take a look at [`Standard TimeSpan Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Custom TimeSpan Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)